# *.onion don't work in Safari

Tags: onion-routing, mac, safari

I install Tor via Homebrew. Set SOCKS to localhost:9050 in System Preferences.

Go to https://check.torproject.org in Safari and get **"Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor."**

When I go to the https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/ I get error

[image: onion error]

On other *.onion sites I'm get same error.

In Chrome all work perfectly.

Comment: Most likely leaking DNS (trying to resolve the .onion and connect directly to the IP, which it won't get) or the browser respecting [RFC 7686](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7686).